# Execute PHP pages as ASPX in IIS 7.0

Tags: iis-7

I have a standard install of IIS 7.0 that is capable of executing ASPX pages.
PHP has not been installed or enabled.

With just adding entries to web.config, is it possible to get IIS 7.0 to execute PHP files as ASPX files?

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=execute+php+in+iis+7.0) is your friend.

Comment: Not with this one it isn't ;o)